# Getting the test name in the afterEach function in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Let me start by saying I am quite new to node.js and mocha.It just breaks my head. I started using the tdd approach and I am trying to get the test that will start or has just finished from within the beforeEach and afterEach functions, but I've had no luck.(I am mostly interested in afterEach). At least I couldn't figure a neat way of doing it. The only thing I could think of was keeping the tests and the suite in a variable and then on afterEach() just do some matching to see which test has finished.

Ideally where it says 'test name' I want to have something like suite.test.name

```
suite('my test suite', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('test name');
    });
    test('first test', function (done) {
        var testarray = ['1', '3', '5', '7'];
        testarray.forEach(function(num, index) {
            console.log('num: ' + num + ' index: ' + index);
        }, 
        done());
    });
    afterEach(){
        console.log('test name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You get the name of the current test with `this.currentTest.title`

```
afterEach(function(){
    console.log(this.currentTest.title)
})
```

Comment: -thanks a lot. I spent ages trying to figure that out. Maybe I should invest some time in test debugging :)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm using mocha 1.12 and getting "after each" hook:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Is there are way to access the list of afterEach and may be add to them?

Comment: *this* solution doesn't seem to work for the 'it' test callback function. What is the syntax for that? in other words, this.currentTest is *not* defined in the it function callback.

Comment: to answer my own question, it's this.test.title in the it(), not this.currentTest.title.

Answer (score 12):

I find that i use `this.currentTest.fullTitle()` more than `this.currentTest.title`-- i prefer to have the `describe` names as well.

Comment: nice, that is exactly what I wanted (the 'describe' value + the 'it' value)

Comment: Check out `this.parent.fullTitle()` gives you the 'describe' value on it's own.

Comment: @mikemaccana Correction: it has to be `this.currentTest.parent.fullTitle()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested describe blocks and for some reason you want to separate the title portions you can do something like the following in either the `beforeEach` or `afterEach` methods:

```
function titles(test) {
    console.log(test.title)
    if (test.parent) {
        titles(test.parent)
    }
}

titles(this.currentTest)
```